# 连……都 structure: is 连去过故宫都没有 correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I've been studying Chinese for about 9 months now and I am a little confused as to how to rewrite this sentence using the 连……都 structure. I've included what I've done but it just does not seem right. Any help would be great!

他在北京住了半年多了，但是还没去过故宫

Is 他在北京住了半年多了, 连去过故宫都没有 correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope.

他在北京住了半年多了, 连故宫都没有去过。

or omit 有

他在北京住了半年多了, 连故宫都没去过。

other examples

```
1.我学英语十多年了，连电影台词都听不懂。

2.我学了十多年英语了，连小说都看不懂。
3.我来过这家饭店很多次了，连他们的招牌菜都没吃过。
4.我认识他3个月了，连他的名字都不知道。


（1）这个箱子连大人都提不动，小孩儿就更加提不动了。
（3）他连这么难的题都会做，真聪明！
（5）你那么大的人，这么不懂礼貌，连小孩儿都不如。
（6）他忙得连睡觉的时间都没有。
```

Answer (score 6):

The more smooth way is:
他在北京半年多了，连 故宫 都 没有去过？
连 in this sentence could be omited, but 都 could not be omited if you want to stress your surprise.

Some examples:

> 1. 这孩子挑食, (连)鸡蛋也不吃.
>    The child is particular about food, he doesn't (even) eat eggs.
> 2. 你(连)看见血都要头晕，怎么能当外科大夫呢？
>    You faint at the sight of blood, how could you become a surgeon?